# angular js multiple checkboxes filters on multilevel JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, checkbox, filter

Hey guys I found this one on multiple checkboxes filter: [angular js multiple checkbox with custom filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522182/angular-js-multiple-checkbox-with-custom-filters)

I have a similar problem but a multilevel JSON.
Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u9a1oLp6/5/

Especialy this part is my problem:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(row){
        var mercChecked = getChecked($scope.merchantCheckboxes);
        var brandChecked = getChecked($scope.brandCheckboxes);
        if(mercChecked.length == 0 && brandChecked.length == 0)
            return true;
        else{
            if($scope.merchantCheckboxes[row.MerchantName])
                return true;
            else{
                return row.BrandList.split(/,\s*/).some(function(brand){
                    return $scope.brandCheckboxes[brand];
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to correct the code which access `BrandList`.

Access it through the `BrandMerchant` array:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(row){
    var mercChecked = getChecked($scope.merchantCheckboxes);
    var brandChecked = getChecked($scope.brandCheckboxes);
    if(mercChecked.length == 0 && brandChecked.length == 0)
        return true;
    else{
        if($scope.merchantCheckboxes[row.MerchantName])
            return true;
        else{
            return row.BrandMerchant[0].BrandList.split(/,\s*/).some(function(brand){
                return $scope.brandCheckboxes[brand];
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Also when you construct the BrandList Array for the right filter:

```
_.each($scope.records, function(i){
   if(i.BrandMerchant[0].BrandList)   
$scope.BrandList=_.union($scope.BrandList,i.BrandMerchant[0].BrandList.split(','       ));
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te2q5bgg/).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is quite simple, you missed out the comma in your json after the BrandMerchant
I found out by looking at the browser's Console.

```
{
        "MerchantName": "amazon",
        "BrandMerchant":[
            {
        "BrandList": " pepe jeans, peter england, red tape"
            }
         ], // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< THIS COMMA HERE
         "Description": "amazon Store"
}
```

Also, not sure if you want to change the Brandlist into an array?
`"BrandList": [item1, item2, etc]`

Comment: Thanks for the issue with the comma but what I mean is the part: 'return row.BrandList.split(/,\s*/).some(function(brand)' It must look something like this: 'return row.BrandMerchant.BrandList.split(/,\s*/).some(function(brand)' to get the right object.